# How to share data across multiple reducers on the same host

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have this situation where I need to make a data set available across multiple reducers. I do not want to load the same data in memory for each reducer, since I do not see it as optimal behavior and the file size is big. I do not want to have the data stored outside the cluster and make a network call instead.

Comment: can you elaborate? Do you want data from mappers reach multiple reducers instead of single reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in DistributedCache could be the only option.

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example, since I'm new to this concept. If I load a file in a DistributedCache, can I access the data across all the reducers?

Comment: After some searches, I was able to find this tutorial. 
https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#auxdata. One thing which I'm not quite sure upon is Distributed cache loads the file locally on the host. Then each mapper instance can load the contents of the file into a data structure, that essentially would consume the same amount of memory (RAM) usage right? Unless I'm missing something here. Could you kindly clarify the same

Comment: By loading it in distributed cache wou would be able to access the file across all reducers. The tasktracker where your reducer is set to run would copy the file to its local disk and you could use the file. But this is optimal only in the case of a small dataset in terms of KB if that is the case it could save some network bandwidth. But if your file is huge then you could create a map file and create the map file in an archive format and add them to the cache using -archive option. You could read The definitive guide to get an example.

Comment: You could get some info on map file in http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/hadoop-io-sequence-map-set-array-bloommap-files/

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem on loading the contents of the file in memory when each reducer task runs. I want to keep less/no overhead on the reducer tasks in accessing these files

Comment: This puts the file in the tasks working directory with -archives option.  From the definitive guide "Copies the specified archives from the local filesystem (or any filesystem if a scheme is
specified) to the shared filesystem used by the jobtracker (usually HDFS), unarchives
them, and makes them available to MapReduce programs in the task’s working
directory."